# find the inverse of $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, modules

Let $\times$ denote the (associative) operation $a \times b = a + b + ab$ (with $+$ defined as usual) and consider the ring $(\mathbb{Z}, \times, +)$.

Find the inverse of the $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{array} \right]^{-1} = \;\;? $$

---

i have that $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ is a group with $a \times b = a + b + ab$. perhaps there's no operation that distributes over this

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Note that this fails to be a ring with the usual $+$.  In particular, $\times$ does not distribute over $+$:
$$
a \times (b + c) = a + b + c + a(b + c)\\
a \times b + a \times c = 2a + b + c + a(b+c)
$$

Comment: How do you define matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

We're looking for the inverse of the matrix $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, with respect to the operation $\times$ that you have defined.

**Hint:** Verify that the $0$-matrix is the multiplicative identity, i.e. $a \times 0 = 0 \times a = a$ for all matrices $a$.  With that in mind, it suffices to solve $A \times X = 0$, i.e.
$$
A + X + AX = 0
$$
for $X$.